# How can i take an excel file, parse it contents and store the column's data of excel sheet in my database column?

Tags: php

There is one excel sheet which contains student name, rollno etc. How can i parse the contents of excel file and store that in my sql database?

Comment: Not that familiar with php, but you can query an excel file just like a database using ADO.  This might be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for **PHPExcel** library i believe.

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

use this class to read the excel files
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader

Comment: Hi Dobiatowski, The links aren't working. I am not able to download the class.

Comment: OK! I change the mirror. Now it got downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it directly from the Excel file, rather than create an intermediate CSV using Excel's "Save As" options, then look at libraries such as [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) that can read the xls binary format and make the data accessible to your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to you that you save it as csv, it's much more easier and less hacking to upload it to the database

here is simple a sample

http://www.bradino.com/php/csv-upload-to-database/

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel is one of the best PHP classes i have ever worked with. In addition to parsing and reading files of all Excel variations (including csv) the output to Excel 2007 + is excellent.

Be sure to look at the documentation and examples...they will get you up to speed very quickly